# como hacer que jquery haga click en un botón de paginación?

Tags: javascript, click, paginacion

tengo la siguiente función para poder usar la paginación de mi sitio

```
       $(document).on('click', '.pagination a', function (event) {
                event.preventDefault();
                event.stopPropagation();

                const templateType = $('#template_type').val();
                page = $(this).attr('href').split('sites=')[1];


                $('li').removeClass('active');
                $(this).parent().addClass('active');

                pagination();
            });
```

sin embargo ahora también quiero hacer via javascript que se haga click dependiendo de un valor que me llegará desde el servidor,

ejemplo: `page = 2:`

como puedo hacer que haga click en la página 2?

Answer (score 0):

En jQuery existe la función `click()`, que, llamada sin argumentos, es equivalente a `trigger('click')`. De cualquiera de las dos formas, basta con seleccionar el elemento que necesitas y hacer el llamado a la función.

[Puedes ver la doc aquí](https://api.jquery.com/click/)